# Moodle 3.4 performance is very poor

Tags: mysql, linux, moodle

I have installation of Moodle 3.4, I'm using VPS hosting with 4 CPU and 8 GB of RAM. My site performed well for two months, and today the performance is very low.

The home page is opening in good performance, but when I tried to login it takes some time, and when I tried to check the plugin overview, it gives 504 error.

I have checked with the host provider about the server performance, and they ensured that the server is performing well. Additionally, I have a WordPress site hosted on the same server, and it is performing excellently.

Incidentally, not all pages gives 504 error, some pages works just fine, some others show pop up dialog with message "undefined".

- Some pages that gives 504 such as Plugins, debugging, etc.
- Some pages gives undefined pop up dialog such as: course pages

Comment: Are you sure you dont have Theme Designer On? Also make sure that moodledata are not on a shared / network disk.

Answer (score 0):

Check your moodledata folder. Don't place it inside HTML folder it will slow up the process. Use Purge Caches option.
Install PHP accelerator for moodle.
Also, refer this link for more optimization https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Performance_recommendations
There is plugin u available in moodle site you can check the benchmark of your site.
https://moodle.org/plugins/report_benchmark